# Visit 12 cities in this word search

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, geography, word-search

Find below 12 cities in this word search puzzle, to find out what you are:

- Algiers
- Barcelona
- Bogotá
- Brisbane
- Buenos Aires
- Cologne
- Gdańsk
- Lagos
- Madrid
- Miami
- Seattle
- Sofia

```
S W E N D S O A W B T A R G E N W
X E I A D N M E R Q P I N J T T A
O P D G A R I A S O O T D N Y I D
B M O L O G E B M L K N J L E N R
I D F U C L A U S T T E G R A A S
A U O B A A N L M R A N D P O W P
C G U A I R A G L A L G E U L I K
O L O M B T V B A L O M R E A O L
S T C A G S U A A I P T I U P T N
W G C U I N E S I T D N A L O V W
X U Z A E N A I R E G L A T E S U
B N A S E I R V E G O M T D W O N
B N Y G E G A N M I I N S S P T I
R A F T A E T P U N A D D T A X T
A M E F A R I A N I P U E T I N U
I R D Y D M E O B V S F I R N I I
S E G Y N A R L E S N I A P S N E
```

> *Don't forget it has a [enigmatic-puzzle](/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle) tag*

Comment: Appears that none of the cities appear in the word search, but there are close matches.

Comment: I've made sense of the first step and (I *think*) the second step of the puzzle too, but don't know how to proceed from there.. just way too many letters :)

Comment: @Prim3numbah, I have tried to have as few as possible letters, but not always it fits right. I'll upvote any good partial answer as well ;)

Comment: Alright, since I can't get any further, I'll post a partial

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [Prim3numbah](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/63733/prim3numbah) showed in [their answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121493/visit-12-cities-in-this-word-search/121523#121523),

> Each of the countries represented by the 12 cities has its name written in a square pattern:
>
>  [image: the word search, with each of the country names highlighted]

From there, I thought I knew what the next step was:

> Each of these cities is pretty easily mapped to a point on a 3x3 grid if you look at it within the borders of its country. For example, Algiers is pretty close to the top-center of Algeria:
>
>  [image: a Google Maps screenshot of Algeria]
>
>  So, doing the same with the square of letters...
>
>  [image: just Algeria's box from the word search, with a star over the letter O in the top center]
>
>  It looks like Algiers should represent the letter O. Unfortunately, with this method, we get the letters OTOLTEETEXDC, which doesn't mean anything, nor does it anagram to anything I can find.

However, thanks to a [helpful tip](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121493/visit-12-cities-in-this-word-search#comment338989_121523) from OP in comments, I tried

> reorienting myself:
>
>  [image: the same completed word search, but rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise]
>
>  As you can see, the eight cardinal and ordinal directions now line up with what we'd expect (i.e. "NW" in the top left corner, "N" in the top middle - albeit confusingly next to another W, etc.) Thanks again to the OP for [some more prodding](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121493/visit-12-cities-in-this-word-search/121531#comment339013_121531) in that direction.
>
>  Now, if we try the same trick, we get the letters TROBITERETOG, which ... is so close to spelling the word **GLOBETROTTER** that it must be the right answer. ([OP confirms](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121493/visit-12-cities-in-this-word-search/121531#comment339012_121531) that the I for Buenos Aires should be an L.)

Comment: looking at it again, I suspect that what happened was rot13(znqevq jnf fhccbfrq gb or na Y ohg tbg birejevggra ol gur havgrq fgngrf - vg'f gur bayl pvgl gung vagrefrpgf jvgu n obeqre yvxr gung). I suspect there's some sort of metaphor there but I can't quite place it...

Comment: I have double checked it myself, and unfortunately, I made one mistake myself: Buenos Aires should be a L instead of an I. Then, if you set the word search in the original way, you should read it correctly from left to right. Madrid is indeed an E

Comment: But please explain in your answer the reorientation. There is a good reason for that. Apart from that, you have got the final answer, well done!

Comment: Nice job :) Didn't think of that step, let alone, erbevragngvba!

Comment: @Lezzup ah, I had buenos aires as an E (in my head it's northeast but looking at a map there's a lot more argentina to its north than I remember). maybe if there was an L there I'd have figured it out, but good to know that I was just as wrong either way

Comment: anyway I've added all that to the answer. a bit mad at myself because of course it seems obvious in hindsight, especially with M Oehm having pretty much pointed it out for me in the other comments. still, despite the error, a very entertaining puzzle!

Comment: @juicifer, you have earned the checkmark, well done! If you know the solution, some things become so obvious, it's hard to imagine how other people will look at it. I hope the puzzle made sense in the end...

Comment: To be fair, I made that quip only after Lezzup hinted at reorientation. If I look clever now, it's all quite undeserved -- I couldn't see any of what you and Prim3numbah solved. (I first thought that I would be a "knight" and the cities were hidden in a knight's tour or maybe I was an "airplane" and we were looking at airports instead.) By the way, your tidy and colourful diagrams are very pretty.

Answer (score 6):

**Partial answer**

First step

> Find the corresponding countries to the cities which, in alphabetical order, are: **Algeria, Argentina, Australia, Bulgaria, Colombia, Germany, Nigeria, Poland, Spain and United States** 
>   [image] 
>  You'll see that each country form a 3x3 square inside (for example you find the square of Argentina by following the letters, in order, until it forms a square; a,r,g,e,n,t,i,n,a,a,r,g,e,n,t,i)

Here´s what I think is the second step:

> Let´s write down all the 3x3 letter squares we've found. 
>  **Algeria:** 
>  [image] 
>  **Argentina:** 
>  [image] 
>  **Australia:** 
>  [image]  
>  **Bulgaria:** 
>  [image] 
>  **Colombia:** 
>  [image] 
>  **Germany:** 
>  [image] 
>  **Nigeria:** 
>  [image] 
>  **Poland:** 
>  [image] 
>  **Spain:** 
>  [image] 
>  **United States:** 
>  [image] 
>  Not sure how to proceed from here... perhaps there´s some way of arranging these to make another wordsearch or similar, but can't see how. I also don't know how to make use of the 3x3 letters to match the specific cities...

Comment: First step 100% correct. I gave you an upvote for that. Do you want a hint on the second step? ;)

Comment: @Lezzup Does the [tag:geography] imply you need to look up a map?

Comment: @newQOpenWid it might come in handy

Comment: @Lezzup Ok, I wasn't sure if step 2 was correct since I couldn't make use of it, felt like too many random letters

Comment: it seems to me like rot13(nyy gur pvgvrf ner cerggl vqragvsvnoyr gb n fcbg ba n 3k3 fdhner (r.t. nytvref vf cerggl zhpu rknpgyl gur gbc-pragre bs nytrevn)) but I tried that and it didn't get me anywhere, so idk

Comment: @juicifer, who says north is at the top? ;)

Comment: @Lezzup most modern day maps, but fair enough I suppose

Comment: @juicifer maybe the top is rot13(qrcraqrag ba jurer gur fdhner 'fgnegf', nf va gur bevragngvba naq cbfvgvba va jurer gur rqtrf bs gur fdhner fcryy bhg gur yrggref.)

Comment: @juicifer: And most old maps feature a compass rose ...

Comment: (But I get an E and an N where I expected an L and a B.)

Comment: @newQOpenWid that's a nice idea but two of them would be left ambiguous if that were the case

Comment: @MOehm I'm having the first problem but not the second

Comment: Yeah. Brisbane isn't Perth, apparently. (Sorry about that.)

Comment: you really do learn something new every day